# popup screen won't show after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

I am building a web app with jquery mobile. On one page I have a little form to make a room reservation. I have two input boxes. In these boxes comes the start DateTime and in the other one the end DateTime.

Now what I do is the following, when I click on the input box there comes an popup box where you can insert a DateTime. The plugin is called [mobiscroll](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/).

I am opening it like this in my JS.

```
  $('[data-role=page]').live('pageinit', function(event){
        $("#DATUM_BEGIN").scroller({ preset: 'datetime',theme: 'jqm', mode: 'mixed',display:'modal'});

        $("#DATUM_EINDE").scroller({ preset: 'datetime',theme: 'jqm', mode: 'mixed',display:'modal'});
});
```

The first time it does is correctly. But If I for example forget to enter the end date and submit my form with the submit button. It shows the error messages on the screen. But whenI then want to enter a date. The popup box won't show.

Does anybody know how I can solve this on a correct way?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Ok I found the solution, you just need to disable the ajax with and it will work.
You can disable your ajax on a form by using the attribute `data-ajax=false`

Comment: You need to find the offending code and post it. It's impossible for us to know what the problem is if we don't have the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
$(page).live('pageinit', function(event){
    // Your code
    // 'page' is a selector for the jquery mobile page you want to work on
});
```

instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

You can see why here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html
I think it might be this problem, but even if it's not, I would work that way, it will avoid several headaches.

Comment: Sorry come again, what should page be in this example ?

Comment: You should use on() or delegate() (delegate in older jquery versions) instead of live() method

Comment: I'm assuming you are using jquery mobile (because of the tag of your post) and you are structuring your html by jquery mobile pages (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html). So, 'page', in this case, is a selector for the page your form is in. Let's suppose your form is wrapped by <div id="myPage" data-role="page"> ... </div>. A valid selector for this page would be $('#myPage')

Comment: Mm no, I am using external pages. Not one big HTML

Comment: Even so, aren't you wrapping the contents of every page you are displaying with <div data-role="page">? Because that's the way to go, if you don't do it, jquery mobile will create that div

Comment: Yes it creates a div, but not with an id in it.

Comment: Yep, so, if you don't wanna create it yourself in your html for some reason, another valid selector would be $('[data-role=page]'), but just if you are sure the document you want to work on has only a page (in case you yourself are not creating more, there's just one of them), otherwise every page of the document would be attached the handler function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11229/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-davids)